# The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment Matlab

Tags: matlab

Trying to write a loop that checks if one norm is bigger than the other.

```
for i = 1:360;
    V1 = X(:, i);
    N1 = norm(V1);
    V2 = X(:, (i+1));
    N2 = norm(V2);
    N1 = highNorm;
    if (N2 >= N1)
        (P = N2)
end
```

However, I'm getting an error associated with P = N2:

Error: The expression to the left of the equals
sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the brackets around `P=N2`

Comment: and put another `end` after your `if` clause

Comment: while we're at it, you'll probably want a semicolon after `P=N2` as well, to suppress output.

Comment: I get undefined function or variable 'highNorm". Sorry, I'm new to matlab, how do I declare variables, I thought they got declared when you used them.

Comment: Yes, they should be declared when you first use them. However, as far as I can see, you've never used `highNorm` (so it's not defined) until you try to set `N1=highNorm`. What is `highNorm` supposed to be?

Comment: On right of assignment means you're using it, not assigning it. How would it know how what `highNorm` is?  Where have you assigned it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D8YUZKTw. Got it to print, however, high norm isn't tracking correctly, like smaller values get assigned to highNorm even though the value isn't greater. How can I fix this?